Why I get error of queryResultSignal() can only be used within an injection context when i use signals in ngneat/query?
I'm trying to integrate @ngneat/query with signals in my Angular application. However, I'm encountering the following error:
Error: NG0203: queryResultSignal() can only be used within an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with `runInInjectionContext`. More details can be found at https://angular.dev/errors/NG0203

In my code example, I'm attempting to load a product based on a parameter from the route. To achieve this, I convert the product parameter into a signal using:
productId = toSignal(
  inject(ActivatedRoute).params.pipe(map((params) => Number(params['id'])))
);

Then, inside the computed function, I call @ngneat/query with that signal.
However, it's not working as expected. What am I missing in my code to make it function correctly?
You can find a StackBlitz demo of my code here.
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, computed, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ActivatedRoute, RouterModule, provideRouter } from '@angular/router';
import { injectQuery } from '@ngneat/query';
import { delay, map, of } from 'rxjs';
import { toSignal } from '@angular/core/rxjs-interop';

import 'zone.js';

console.clear();

@Component({
  standalone: true,
  selector: 'product',
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
    in product: 
    <ng-container *ngIf="product() as product">
      {{product.data |json}}
    </ng-container>
  `,
})
export class ProductComponent {
  query = injectQuery();
  productId = toSignal(
    inject(ActivatedRoute).params.pipe(map((params) => Number(params['id'])))
  );

  product = computed(() => this.getProduct(this.productId()!).result());

  getProduct(id: number) {
    return this.query({
      queryKey: ['product', id],
      queryFn: () => of({ id }).pipe(delay(2 * 1000)), // <-- replace http call here
    });
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterModule],
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{ name }}!</h1>
    <a [routerLink]="['/1']">goto product 1</a>
    <hr>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
}

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [provideRouter([{ path: ':id', component: ProductComponent }])],
});


Stackblitz does not work

i updated the link in the question. thanks.

I think the signal can only be executed at the root of the component ( We cannot create a signal inside the computed block), which is not suitable for you in a reactive context. The solution I am providing is to return an observable instead and get the data using async pipe.
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, computed, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ActivatedRoute, RouterModule, provideRouter } from '@angular/router';
import { injectQuery } from '@ngneat/query';
import { delay, map, of, startWith } from 'rxjs';
import { toSignal } from '@angular/core/rxjs-interop';

import 'zone.js';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

console.clear();

@Component({
  standalone: true,
  selector: 'product',
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
    in product: 
    <ng-container *ngIf="product() | async as product">
      {{product | json}}
    </ng-container>

  `,
})
export class ProductComponent {
  query = injectQuery();
  productId = toSignal(
    inject(ActivatedRoute).params.pipe(map((params) => Number(params['id'])))
  );

  product = computed(() => this.getProduct(this.productId()!).result$);

  getProduct(id: number) {
    return this.query({
      queryKey: ['product', id],
      queryFn: () => of({ id }).pipe(startWith(null), delay(2 * 1000)), // <-- replace http call here
    });
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterModule],
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{ name }}!</h1>

    <a [routerLink]="['/1']">goto product 1</a>
    <a [routerLink]="['/2']">goto product 2</a>
    <hr>

    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
}

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [provideRouter([{ path: ':id', component: ProductComponent }])],
});

Stackblitz Demo
